# SCSS nth-child grid layout

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I'm having trouble with this.
I have a bootstrap 3 site with html like this:

```
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="item">
    </div>
    // and so on...
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to make it so that the last "row" (not bootstrap row) of `col`'s get `margin-bottom: 0`

When device is `xs` screen size:

```
.item-container {
  .row {
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-4 {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      @media screen and (max-width: $xs-max) {
        &:last-child {
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When device is `sm` screen size:

```
.item-container {
  .row {
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-4 {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      @media screen and (max-width: $xs-max) {
        &:last-child,
        &:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd) {
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That worked fine selecting the last "row".
However, I'm having trouble with the three column rows. Trying to select the last row.

I've made a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rx03nan6/

I'm trying to select the red boxes.

`<hr />` is just a break line to show you different types of layout it can have depending on the number of boxes.
`<br />` please ignore the br tag, I just wanted the show you how it looks like, so please don't look into the HTML in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to style only the items on the last row, where each row contains 3 items.

You can't simply select the last 3 items with `:nth-last-child(-n + 3)` because let's say you have 4 items - that would select items 2,3,4 - when we only want to select item 4.

So we need additional logic here:

1) We always select the **last item**

2) We only want to select the **second last item** if it is also item (3n + 2) - 2,5,8,etc.

3) We only want to select the **third last item** if it is also item (3n + 1) - 1,4,7,etc.

So the selector will look something like this:

```
li:nth-child(3n + 1):nth-last-child(-n + 3),
li:nth-child(3n + 2):nth-last-child(-n + 2),
li:last-child {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

### Here's a [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/AXVKRY?editors=1100#0)

### Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rx03nan6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution for number of column like one , two and three column. There is no need to add nth child. this solution depend on parent class like .raw class

```
.item-container {
  .row {
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-4 {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
   @media screen and (max-width: $xs-max) {
        & > div:last-child {
          margin-bottom: 0 !important;
        }
      }
  }
}
```